# Can I run grafana outside of firewall

Tags: influxdb, grafana

#### I'll have influxDB storing arduino sensor data. I need to visualize this.

I want admins(around 100 people) go to their browser, type www.example.com, fill in their username and password, and see Grafana 10 visualization belongs to them from 1000 vizualizations. Is it possible with grafana or should I use something else?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I installed my influxdb, got data from arduino, tried chronograf to visualize, there wasn't option to authenticate & authorize. So I wonder mby grafana may do this. Didn't try anything with grafana yet.

Answer (score 0):

In short yes.

To put it simple, Grafana only knows how to plot data, what you need to do is provide those data.

Commonly Grafana is used with Graphite, but you're absolutely not forced to use it, and have in fact various alternative for your datasource; InfluxDB is one of those. If you haven't yet done it, I suggest you to read more at http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/influxdb/

From your instance of Grafana click on Dashboards and select Data Sources; there you'll be able to select `InfluxDB 0.9.x` or `InfluxDB 0.8.x` and continue providing required data.

What you'll need is configure your architecture to give access to the InfluxDB from both your Arduino application(s) (to push/store data) and Grafana (to pull data).

Comment: Ok, let's say I got my fancy visualizations in grafana,  but how can I authenticate and authorize those who visit grafana instance via browser.

Comment: Grafana has its authentication and each user can build his own dashboard. As an alternative you can always configure your web server to ask for authentication when getting to some page. You may want to look for (as minimum) basic authentication.